# Complex CSS positioning

Tags: css, html, css-position

I want to achieve this positioning using CSS :

[image]

But the best I obtain after days of tries is this :

[image]

Can you help me to achieve that positioning, taking into account :

- the red comments in the "try" picture (see JSFiddle below) indicating some major constraints
- that the positioning should work on IE8+, FF10+, Chrome, Opera, Safari (using CSSPie and selectivizr for IE8 compatibility)

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LHVX/)** and the code :

HTML

```
<body>body (all divs may have some padding, some margin and some border. All divs adjust their height to their content.)
<div id="globalcontainer"><span class="important">#globalcontainer (fixed width, not really centered into body : see center)</span>
  <div id="header">#header (100%)</div>
<div id="middle">#middle (100%)
  <div id="left">
    <span class="important">#left (on the left of content, with a fixed min-width.<br>
     <br>
 Width adjusted to content if content &gt; min-width. <br>
<br>
      If left+right+center min-width &gt; global container width, then still adjusts its size to its content and goes outside globalcontainer limits.<br>
<br>
      Inner divs have variable (and unknown) width, sticked to the right)</span>
      <br>
      <DIV class="bloc" style="width:300px;">bloc</div>
      <DIV class="bloc" style="width:50px;">bloc</div>
      <DIV class="bloc" style="width:500px;">bloc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="center"><span class="important">#center (width adjusted to globalcontainer size - left size - right size, with a fixed min-width.<br>
      <br>
      Stays centered on the screen whatever the left or right size are<br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; --&gt; if left or right divs are not present in the HTML (or present with display:none), center div stays on the center of the screen)</span>
    <div id="center-middlerow">#center-middlerow (100%)
      <div id="pageReceiver">#pageReceiver (100%)
        <div id="page">#page (100%)<br>
          <div id="pageHeader">#pageHeader (100%)</div>
          <div id="pageContent">#pageContent (100%)</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tip" style="display: block;">#tip (under page)</div>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align:center" id="center-bottomrow">#center-bottomrow (100%)</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"><span class="important">#right (on the right of content, with a fixed min-width.<br>
<br>
Width adjusted to content if content &gt; min-width. <br>
<br>
If left+right+center min-width &gt; global container width, then still adjusts its size to its content and goes outside globalcontainer limits.<br>
<br>
Inner divs have variable (and unknown) width, sticked to the right )</span>
      <br>
      <DIV class="bloc" style="width:30px;">bloc</div>
      <DIV class="bloc" style="width:60px;">bloc</div>
      <DIV class="bloc" style="width:90px;">bloc</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">#footer (100%)</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;

    background-color:rgba(125,125,125,0.1); 
}

span {
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
}

span.important {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
html {
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:white;
}

/* Real CSS starting here */
BODY {
    padding:20px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

#globalcontainer, #left, #center, #right , #header, #footer {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    display:table;
}

/* ====================================================== */

#globalcontainer {
    min-width:1130px;
    max-width:1130px;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#header {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
}

#middle {
    display: table;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#footer {
    margin-top:10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

/* ====================================================== */

#left {
    vertical-align:top;
    float:left;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#center {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
}

#center-toprow {
    padding:10px;
    padding-top:0px;
}

#center-middlerow {
}

#center-bottomrow {
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:30px;
}

#right {
    vertical-align:top;
    float:right;
    padding-left:20px;
}


#left DIV.bloc {
    float:right;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#right DIV.bloc {
    float:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

/* ====================================================== */

#pageReceiver {
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}

#page {
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:20px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    min-height:591px;
}

#pageHeader {
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom:15px;

    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}

#tip {
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:transparent;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: One question: is the #center always higher than #left and #right?

Comment: @chadocat : center is always at same level than left and right.  In real situation, the first .bloc is at the same level than pageHeader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a complex layout, along with `border-box` you also will need to carefully tweak the dimensions for the desired look.

Check this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/SXJuT/** (hope it looks like your screenshot)

Full screen: **http://jsfiddle.net/SXJuT/embedded/result/**

*CSS*:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; font-size: 9px; }
div { border: 1px solid blue; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 2px; margin: 4px; }
#globalcontainer { width: 99%; height: 98%; background-color: #deebf7; }
#header { height: 5%; background-color: #d1e4f3; }
#middle { height: 86%; background-color: #d1e4f3; display: table; border-spacing: 4px; width: 99%; }
#footer { height: 5%; background-color: #d1e4f3; }
#left, #center, #right { display: table-cell; background-color: #c4ddf1; }
#left { width: 14%; }
#center { width: 68%; }
#right {  width: 14%; }
#center-middlerow { height: 80%; background-color: #bad5eb; }
#center-bottomrow { height: 20%; background-color: #bad5eb; }
#pageReceiver { height: 78%; background-color: #b1d0ec; }
#tip { height: 16%; background-color: #b1d0ec; }
#page { height: 95%; background-color: #a7cbe9; }
#pageHeader { height: 14%; background-color: #2e75b5; }
#pageContent { height: 62%; background-color: #2e75b5; }
#pageFooter { height: 14%; background-color: #2e75b5; }
.bloc { height: 20%; background-color: #2e75b5; }
#left > .bloc:nth-child(1), #right > .bloc:nth-child(1) { width: 50%; }
#left > .bloc:nth-child(2), #right > .bloc:nth-child(2) { width: 70%; }
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposal. But the design you give do not meet many of the requirements. For example, #center do not take the available space. I doubt about the ability for left and right to expand until the limit then go outside them, ... I'll make some tests on the basis you propose, but I'm not confident about the result on a first approach.

Comment: Hello. I've made many tries and adjustments, and even if your initial proposal did not meet the asked requirements, it was indeed a very good basis on wich I have been able to build a full design that meets my wishes. Thank you ! I just have to test it now for FF10 and IE8 and hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Going with the border-box box model is the right way to go.

Here is a structure I often use : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7HSTV/2/)

It uses some wrapper divs with `position: relative;` and custom padding, containing absolutely positioned elements with `height: 100%;` and `overflow :auto;`.

It needs tweaking but you'll get the gist.

HTML

```
<div id="globalcontainer">
    <div id="global-wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="middle-wrapper">
            <div id="left">
                <div class="bloc"></div>
                <div class="bloc"></div>
                <div class="bloc"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="center-wrapper">
                <div id="center">
                    <div id="center-middlerow"></div>
                    <div id="center-bottomrow"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <div class="bloc"></div>
                <div class="bloc"></div>
                <div class="bloc"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
html,
body{
    height: 100%;
}
#globalcontainer{
    height: 100%;
}
#global-wrapper{
    padding: 100px 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
}
#header,
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
}
#header{
    top: 0;
}
#middle{
    height: 100%;
}
#middle-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 200px;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
}
#left,
#right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#left{
    left: 0;
}
#right{
    right: 0;
}
#center{
    height: 100%;
}
#center-wrapper{
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
.block{
    background: #fff;
}
```